# Can we create .mobileconfig file programmatically?

Tags: ios

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AutoJoin</key>
            <true/>
            <key>EncryptionType</key>
            <string>WPA</string>
            <key>HIDDEN_NETWORK</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>12345678</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures wireless connectivity settings.</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Wi-Fi (WIFI1)</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.orgName.p2m.wifi</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>orgName</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.wifi.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>3FEF4439-A554-4CB9-8CD6-6D842D1612F4</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>SSID_STR</key>
            <string>WIFI1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>AutoJoin</key>
            <true/>
            <key>EncryptionType</key>
            <string>WPA</string>
            <key>HIDDEN_NETWORK</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>12345678</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures wireless connectivity settings.</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Wi-Fi (WIFI2)</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.orgName.p2m.wifi1</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>orgName</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.wifi.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>00846FEC-0649-48D1-81FC-508D9E167436</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>SSID_STR</key>
            <string>WIFI2</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>This profile will be installed to allow connectivity to the internet and network resources of Please2Meet locations. If this profile is removed, all internet and network access will be removed for orgName locations.</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>HotspotProfile</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.orgName.p2m</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>orgName</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>D285694F-9975-4A0E-8B88-F245FE607885</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Is it possible to create .mobileconfig file in iOS with wifi payloads?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to create an XML file through code?

Comment: What problem are you having with creating it? If you just want to know if it is possible then **YES** it is possible.

Comment: It is showing "Invalid profile. Contact to administrator"

Comment: Also can we sign profile programmatically?